# Can high amperes damage servo motor?

Tags: power-supply, arduino, amperage, servo

I have 5 servo motor Futaba s3003 and DC Adapter 6V - 2A, I'm asking if I used this adapter on these servos will be okay or not?

single servo stall current around **250mA not sure** and 8mA/idle

Comment: High current can damage virtually anything. But it is unrelated to the maximum current rating of the power supply. For that there is a comprehensive answer here: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/34745/choosing-power-supply-how-to-get-the-voltage-and-current-ratings

Comment: Small 9g servos with less than half the torque of the ones you're using tend to have a stall current of ~800mA, so I'd expect the stall current of your servos to be close to 2A. As explained in the linked question, the servos will only draw the current they need from the power supply, so no need to worry about damaging them. What you should be worried about is damaging the wall adapter, since the total stall current of the 5 servos will be around 10A. What's your application? If the load on the servos is light enough, you might be able to get away with it.